# Umbraco System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException

Tags: c#, sql-server, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created a MVC project and then installed Umbraco CMS version 7.4.0 and debugged it runs good. Then I have installed the EventCalender plugin and then debugged caused an error

> The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name =
> uniqueId ]
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column
> name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = uniqueId ]

The stack traced information was

> [SqlCeException (0x80004005): The column name is not valid. [ Node
> name (if any) = ,Column name = uniqueId ]]
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) +48
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan() +644
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options) +543
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +21
> StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in
> c:\Code\github\SamSaffron\MiniProfiler\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:279
> Umbraco.Core.Persistence.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
> +55    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Func`1 func) +170    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy cmdRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy conRetryPolicy) +118  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy retryPolicy) +52    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry(IDbCommand command) +48    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.Insert(String tableName, String primaryKeyName, Boolean autoIncrement, Object poco) +2149    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.Insert(Object poco) +51    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.MacroRepository.PersistNewItem(IMacro entity) +121    Umbraco.Core.Cache.DefaultRepositoryCachePolicy`2.Create(TEntity
> entity, Action`1 persistNew) +409    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`2.PersistNewItem(IEntity
> entity) +172
> Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UnitOfWork.ScopeUnitOfWork.Commit(Action`1 transactionCompleting) +63    Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UnitOfWork.ScopeUnitOfWork.Commit() +7    Umbraco.Core.Services.MacroService.Save(IMacro macro, Int32 userId) +275    Umbraco.Core.Services.PackagingService.ImportMacros(XElement element, Int32 userId, Boolean raiseEvents) +551    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.Installer.InstallBusinessLogic(Int32 packageId, String tempDir) +2976    A.F.b() +221    A.F.a() +86    A.F.A() +87    EventCalendar.Umbraco.StartUp.OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext) +30    Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.<Complete>b__38_0(IApplicationEventHandler x) +230    Umbraco.Core.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach(IEnumerable`1
> items, Action`1 action) +141    Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.Complete(Action`1 afterComplete) +286
> Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.Complete(Action`1 afterComplete) +93
> Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) +262
> Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.Application_Start(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) +34
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The column name is not valid. [ Node name
> (if any) = ,Column name = uniqueId ]]
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
> context, HttpApplication app) +10107111
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +123
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +181
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +228
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +314
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The column name is not valid. [ Node name
> (if any) = ,Column name = uniqueId ]]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10087352
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +263

What to do to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an unsupported version of the Plugin for that version of Umbraco? Can't say for sure, but this should hopefully get you back running **if the plugin is to blame**.

- Go on the file system and delete the entire plugin folder for this plugin
  from the App_Plugins directory.
- Next I would edit the project file in a text editor and remove all
  references to the plugin.
- Check your packages.config and remove any references from there
- Check the packages folder (I wouldn't expect it to be there, but just
  in case) and delete any references to the calendar plugin if found

Comment: Yeah! hopefully it works now.....